# How much info about JBoss can I get from Linux CLI

Tags: java, linux, jboss

How much info can I get about the JBoss instances running on a linux server. I would like to be able to see what modules are loaded in each server, what ports are used and if the loaded apps are working. I would like to do this in a lightway way using only avaliable commands on Linux.

So far all I have is:

```
pgrep -f jboss
```

Wich gives me the pid of the java instances running JBoss.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes

Answer (score 0):

To get some internal informations from a running JBoss instance you can use it's command line interface.

Good point to start would be https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes